# Problem with Setting up Raspberry Pi 3B+ as WPA2 Enterprise access point

Tags: wpa, hostapd

NOTE: Although this seems to be a `hostapd` problem, however, this problem exists on RP only and that's why I'm posting it here. So please do not downvote because it seems like a `hostapd` problem and not RP.

I'm trying to setup a WPA2 Enterprise hotspot using a Raspberry Pi 3B+. I successfully built and installed Freeradius 3.0.17 on the RP, and tested it with `radtest`. I also managed to setup an access point using `hostapd` for a `WPA-PSK` network, as well as `WPA-EAP` but only for `wpa1` (`wpa=1` in `hostapd` config file). This is the configuration that works for `wpa1`:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=whatever
hw_mode=g
channel=7
ieee8021x=1
auth_algs=1
eap_server=0
eapol_key_index_workaround=0

wpa=1
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
rsn_pairwise=TKIP
wpa_group_rekey=300
wpa_gmk_rekey=640
auth_server_addr=127.0.0.1
auth_server_port=1812
auth_server_shared_secret=testing123
acct_server_addr=127.0.0.1
acct_server_port=1813
acct_server_shared_secret=testing123
```

This also works when I set the `rsn_pairwise` to `CCMP`. But it doesn't work anymore when I set `wpa=2`. The log for `hostapd` is available [here](https://pastebin.com/iwF1CAQY).

I will highly appreciate if someone could help me with this.

EDIT:

Here's the documentation description for `wpa` field in `hostapd` configuration:

```
# This field is a bit field that can be used to enable WPA (IEEE 802.11i/D3.0)
# and/or WPA2 (full IEEE 802.11i/RSN):
# bit0 = WPA
# bit1 = IEEE 802.11i/RSN (WPA2) (dot11RSNAEnabled)
# Note that WPA3 is also configured with bit1 since it uses RSN just like WPA2.
# In other words, for WPA3, wpa=2 is used the configuration (and
# wpa_key_mgmt=SAE for WPA3-Personal instead of wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK).
#wpa=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue comes from kernel and hostapd service in raspbian jessie. In your logs in 385 line you can notice that 4-way handshake has never ending and it stoped on third step. It could be exception in pseudorandom generator.

You can use external WiFi dongle as a workaround now, or wait for a patch.

Comment: Thank you I actually ended up doing the same thing on a laptop instead of RP